# How does friction cause a spinning top to fall?

Tags: angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, friction, rigid-body-dynamics, dissipation

I am wondering how friction can create a torque to change the angular momentum and cause a spinning top to tilt, like in the diagram of a close up of the rounded tip of a top

[image: close up of rounded tip of top]
while the angular velocity of the top continues to decrease.
I don't understand how a friction force can create a torque that causes the top to tilt while at the same time does not increase the angular velocity.

In order for the top to fall, there must be a torque in the opposite direction of the torque which caused the top to rise, so that it will cause the angular momentum to become less vertical. However, if the torque is a result of sliding friction acting on P pointing out of the page, it will cause an increase in ω which clearly cannot occur as the top loses angular velocity over time.

I've found several sources describing why tops will counterintuitively *rise* to a sleeping position before ultimately falling down (E.g. Cross [2013](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Rod_Cross2/publication/258757498_The_rise_and_fall_of_spinning_tops/links/5951a7dba6fdcc218d24c9b4/The-rise-and-fall-of-spinning-tops.pdf) or [2018](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1361-6404/aa997b/pdf) which build on/refute some claims made by Crabtree [1909](https://archive.org/details/elementarytreatm00crabiala/page/n6) and others).

(The way a top rises is also due to friction (previously thought to be sliding friction, but Cross reasons that it's rolling resistance). Whether its sliding friction or rolling resistance, either way it creates a torque which causes the angular momentum to change and become more vertical. However, this only occurs if the initial angular velocity is high enough, and all tops will have to fall eventually regardless of if they reach a sleeping position given the imperfections in the material, friction, air resistance, etc.. )

Crabtree (pg 49 and 139) says that there is a friction force retarding the precession which will cause the top to fall, and he acknowledges that while this will increase ω,

> There is a small frictional couple at the toe, due to the toe not being a mathematical point.

which causes the top to fall and reduce ω at the same time.

So my question is, I understand that friction is causing the top to fall, but I'm mainly confused about the specifics of it. E.g. in what direction does the friction act? What kind of friction is it? How does it work and reduce angular velocity at the same time? I'm looking for something that's representable in a free-body diagram. And what is this "frictional couple" that Crabtree mentions supposed to be? Is it alluding to rolling resistance?